# transaction issue

Tags: bitcoin-core

In the absence of someone at home, I noticed two incomprehensible transactions. Why does a large transaction with a n/a address? Or is this some kind of trick of the BItcoin Core [image]client?

Comment: Did you do anything abnormal with your wallet recently? Did you restore a backup? Since you don't recognize those transactions, is it possible that your wallet has been compromised?

Comment: nothing at all, it simply loaded with OS. because of BTC price, i tried to forget about it for some time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think that is when you send yourself bitcoin. I.e. for consolidating utxos

Comment: may be, but my balance is 0 now. about 0.8 btc dissapeared